# XAMPP managing headers (server response headers)

Tags: apache, xampp, http-headers

I need to modify my localhost page server response (edit headers) - I'm using XAMPP (apache + msql, on linux machine). I can't find how to do that. Maybe some of the programmers/admins know how I can make it happened - share their knowledge and save me time.

If there is any article/link I would use it gladly.

I cannot use live server (my page is a total mess - it working on localhost by miracle...), and the only thing I have installed is xampp, so editing response headers through xampp would be perfect.

Thanks for any directions.

EDIT:
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/modifying-http-headers

is not working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Test "testing"
</IfModule>
```

inside of .htaccess

Comment: Why do you need to modify the headers? What should be the outcome? What have you tried to check why your approach is not working?

Comment: I need to test some app behaviors, I cannot do it live (my app is a mess anyway so moving it from development to production is impossible atm). The steps are described - I have create .htaccess file with the above content - it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you .htaccess file (witch should be placed where your index.html is) type:

```
### add custom header to all server responses from ALL files:
Header add Custom-Header: "parameter=value"

### add custom header to SINGLE file:
<Files someOtherFile.html>
  Header add Custom-Header: "parameter=value"
</Files>
```

I'm using linux, maybe on windows there is something more you should do but remember to restart xampp after editing .htaccess.